# Using R to download URL by linkname in a search function

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping

I want to scrape information from [this](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/news) page for each month with a few parameters, download all returning articles and look for some information.

Scraping works fine with css selector, for example getting the article names:

```
library(rvest)

browseURL("http://www.sueddeutsche.de/news")

#headings Jan 2015

url_parsed1 <- read_html("http://www.sueddeutsche.de/news?search=Fl%C3%BCchtlinge&sort=date&dep%5B%5D=politik&typ%5B%5D=article&sys%5B%5D=sz&catsz%5B%5D=alles&time=2015-01-01T00%3A00%2F2015-12-31T23%3A59&startDate=01.01.2015&endDate=31.01.2015")
headings_nodes1 <- html_nodes(url_parsed1, css = ".entrylist__title")
headings1 <- html_text(headings_nodes1)
headings1 <- str_replace_all(headings1, "\\n|\\t|\\r", "") %>% str_trim()
head(headings1)
headings1
```

But now i want to download the articles for every entrylist_link that the search returns ( for example [here](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/news?search=Fl%C3%BCchtlinge&sort=date&dep%5B%5D=politik&typ%5B%5D=article&sys%5B%5D=sz&catsz%5B%5D=alles&time=2015-01-01T00%3A00%2F2015-12-31T23%3A59&startDate=01.01.2015&endDate=31.01.2015)).

How can i do that? I followed advices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673331/using-r-to-get-download-url-by-link-name) , because the URLs aren´t regular and have different numbers for each article at the end, but it doesnt work.

Somehow i´m not able to get the entrylist_link information with the href information.

I think getting all the links together in a vector is the biggest problem

Can someone give me suggestions on how to get this to work?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on the page and click inpect (I'm using a Chrome Web Browswer), you can see more detail for the underlying xml. I was able to pull all the links under the headings:

```
library(rvest)

browseURL("http://www.sueddeutsche.de/news")
url_parsed1 <- read_html("http://www.sueddeutsche.de/news?search=Fl%C3%BCchtlinge&sort=date&dep%5B%5D=politik&typ%5B%5D=article&sys%5B%5D=sz&catsz%5B%5D=alles&time=2015-01-01T00%3A00%2F2015-12-31T23%3A59&startDate=01.01.2015&endDate=31.01.2015")

headings_nodes1 <- html_nodes(url_parsed1, ".entrylist__link, a")
html_links <- html_attr(headings_nodes1, "href")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Biggest problem was a typo...
url_parsed1 <- read_html("http://www.sueddeutsche.de/news?search=Fl%C3%BCchtlinge&sort=date&dep%5B%5D=politik&typ%5B%5D=article&sys%5B%5D=sz&catsz%5B%5D=alles&time=2015-01-01T00%3A00%2F2015-12-31T23%3A59&startDate=01.01.2015&endDate=31.01.2015")
headings_nodes2 <- html_nodes(url_parsed1, css = ".entrylist__link")
html_links <- html_attr(headings_nodes2, "href")

works fine :)
just need to download them without an entity error now.