# Using str_match_all to match beginning and end of characters in R

Tags: regex, string-matching, rvest, stringr

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am trying to extract unique digital identifiers from a website using stringR. There are several unique doi in the website and after the doi ends it is followed by a " Cite" character.

[1] I get information from a website
pg <- read_html("https://search.datacite.org/works?query=Movebank&resource-type-id=dataset")
[2] I try to get 26 unique character strings from the website that start with "doi"

[3] 
I was planning on using string_match_all with the beginning having to match "https://doi.org/", some characters in between "*" and the end having to match the word "Cite".

str_match_all( html_text(html_nodes(pg, "body")) , pattern = "^https://doi.org/*Cite$")
[4] An example of how one of these doi would look like is:

https://doi.org/10.5441/001/1.41076dq1/6  Cite

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a similar code to hrbrmstr's from below answer, you can get all urls you want easily. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46674097/10710995

```
fils <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//a[contains(@href, 'doi.org')]")

df <- data.frame(link= html_attr(fils, "href"))

 df
                                          link
1  https://doi.org/10.25504/fairsharing.httzv2
2     https://doi.org/10.5441/001/1.41076dq1/6
3     https://doi.org/10.5441/001/1.q986rc29/3
4     https://doi.org/10.5441/001/1.q986rc29/4
5       https://doi.org/10.5441/001/1.25551gr6
6     https://doi.org/10.5441/001/1.25551gr6/1
7     https://doi.org/10.5441/001/1.25551gr6/2
8     https://doi.org/10.5441/001/1.q8b02dc5/4
```